# How to edit the selection fields that are shown in the preferred method of contact field

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I would like to remove the `fax` option from the preferred method of contact picker. Currently the options of `Any` `Email` `Phone` `Fax` and `Mail` are shown (image included below) and I would like to remove `Fax` from the list. I am currently using

```
var preferredContactMethodCode = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('preferredcontactmethodcode').getValue();
```

to access the values but I don't know how to edit the values. Any documentation that you can find on the subject would be greatly appreciated as well.

[image: preferred method of contact screen-capture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [RemoveOption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/gg334266(v=crm.7).aspx#BKMK_removeOption) to remove the option set option at run time.

```
Xrm.Page.getControl('preferredcontactmethodcode').removeOption(4); //4-Fax
```

To remove the option set altogether (which I would never suggest doing on an out of the box field), customize the option set (CRM customizations, field customizations) and remove/delete the option set option (You will lose data).

Answer (score 1):

That field is an option set. You can edit that field using the customisation part of the settings area, as long as you have the  system customiser or a system admin security role.

for more information you can look here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/dynamics/crm-customer-center/create-or-edit-entity-fields.aspx

and for option set specific edits this documentation is available:
https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn531201.aspx